# How can i add dropdown list with files name in footer section?

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, drop-down-menu, footer

My problem is the next:
I have to make a page which must contain test questions.
I already made it for normal questions, but in the next point, i need a dropdown list in the footer template where the user can choose images names from this list and the textbox get the file path.

The files path is the following:
"~/Dokuments/" + v_tren_dirnev(different folder for every test) + "/Teszt/"

The code for aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Kerdesek_Valaszok.aspx.cs" Inherits="Kerdesek_Valaszok" %>
<%@ Register Src="UserControl/AutoRedirect.ascx" TagName="AutoRedirect" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" 
runat="Server">
<uc1:AutoRedirect ID="AutoRedirect1" runat="server" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSTreningek" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbcs %>"SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [trening] WHERE ([tren_deleted] = @tren_deleted)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="tren_deleted" Type="Boolean" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsKerdesek" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeleteKerdes" InsertMethod="InsertKerdes" SelectMethod="GetAllKerdes" TypeName="trening.KerdesekDataAccessLayer" UpdateMethod="UpdateKerdes">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="TrenId" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="KerdId" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="KerdTrenId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="KerdKerdes" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="KerdId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="KerdKerdes" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsValaszok" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeleteValasz" InsertMethod="InsertValasz" SelectMethod="GetAllValasz" TypeName="trening.ValaszokDataAccessLayer" UpdateMethod="UpdateValasz">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="KerdId" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ValaId" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ValaKerdId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ValaValasz" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ValaHelyes" Type="Boolean" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ValaId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ValaValasz" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ValaHelyes" Type="Boolean" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<br />
<table id="kerdesek_valaszok">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <h2>Tréning kérdések és válaszok karbantartása</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTreningek" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDSTreningek" DataTextField="tren_megnevezes" DataValueField="tren_id" Font-Size="Large" AutoPostBack="True" OnDataBound="ddlTreningek_DataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTreningek_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvKerdesek" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="kerd_id" DataSourceID="odsKerdesek" CellPadding="4" ShowFooter="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnRowCommand="gvKerdesek_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvKerdesek_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="kerd_id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="kerd_id" Visible="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("kerd_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("kerd_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="kerd_tren_id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="kerd_tren_id" Visible="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("kerd_tren_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("kerd_tren_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kérdések" SortExpression="kerd_kerdes">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("kerd_kerdes") %>' MaxLength="250" Size="100"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Kötelező a kérdést megadni!" ValidationGroup="update" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("kerd_kerdes") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txbNewKerdes" runat="server" MaxLength="250" Size="100"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTextBox2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Kötelező az új kérdést megadni" ValidationGroup="insert" ControlToValidate="txbNewKerdes" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdateKerdes" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="update" CommandName="UpdateKerdes" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("kerd_id") %>' ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/update.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Módosítás" />
                            &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancelKerdes" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/cancel.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Mégsem" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEditKerdes" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="EditKerdes" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("kerd_id") %>' ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/edit.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Szerkesztés" />
                            &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSelectKerdes" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="SelectKerdes" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("kerd_id") %>' ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/select.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Kiválasztás" />
                            &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDeleteKerdes" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="DeleteKerdes" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("kerd_id") %>' ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/delete.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Törlés"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Biztosan törölni akarja ezt a kérdést és a hozzátartozó válaszokat?');" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnInsertKerdes" CausesValidation="true"  ValidationGroup="insert" runat="server" OnClick="btnInsertKerdes_Click" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/insert.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Új kérdés rögzítése" />

                            <!--AG dropdown list -->
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

                            </FooterTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FF9900" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" ValidationGroup="insert" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" ValidationGroup="update" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary3" ValidationGroup="insertValasz" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary4" ValidationGroup="updateValasz" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="gvValaszok" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="vala_id" DataSourceID="odsValaszok" ShowFooter="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" EmptyDataText="Nincsenek még válaszok megadva!" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnRowCommand="gvValaszok_RowCommand">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="vala_id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="vala_id" Visible="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("vala_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vala_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="vala_kerd_id" SortExpression="vala_kerd_id" Visible="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("vala_kerd_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vala_kerd_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNewValaKerdId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vala_kerd_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Válaszok" SortExpression="vala_valasz">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vala_valasz") %>' MaxLength="250" size="100"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vala_valasz") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txbNewValasz" runat="server" MaxLength="250" size="100"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTextBox3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Kötelező az új választ megadni" ValidationGroup="insertValasz" ControlToValidate="txbNewValasz" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Helyes-e?" SortExpression="vala_helyes">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("vala_helyes") %>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("vala_helyes") %>' Enabled="false" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxNewHelyes" runat="server" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdateValasz" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="UpdateValasz" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("vala_id") %>' ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/update.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Módosítás" />
                            &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancelValasz" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/cancel.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Mégsem" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEditValasz" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/edit.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Szerkesztés" />
                            &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDeleteValasz" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="DeleteValasz" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("vala_id") %>' ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/delete.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Törlés" OnClientClick="return confirm('Biztosan törölni akarja ezt a választ?');" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnInsertValasz" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="insertValasz" runat="server" OnClick="btnInsertValasz_Click" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Theme1/insert.png" Height="25" ToolTip="Új kérdés rögzítése" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The code behind this:

```
public partial class Kerdesek_Valaszok : System.Web.UI.Page{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
}   

protected void btnInsertKerdes_Click(object sender,  EventArgs e)
{
    odsKerdesek.InsertParameters["KerdTrenId"].DefaultValue = ddlTreningek.SelectedValue;
    odsKerdesek.InsertParameters["KerdKerdes"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvKerdesek.FooterRow.FindControl("txbNewKerdes")).Text;
    odsKerdesek.Insert();
    gvKerdesek.DataBind();
}

protected void btnInsertValasz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gvKerdesek.SelectedRow != null)
    {
        odsValaszok.InsertParameters["ValaKerdId"].DefaultValue = ((Label)gvValaszok.Rows[0].FindControl("Label3")).Text;
        odsValaszok.InsertParameters["ValaValasz"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvValaszok.FooterRow.FindControl("txbNewValasz")).Text;
        odsValaszok.InsertParameters["ValaHelyes"].DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)gvValaszok.FooterRow.FindControl("cbxNewHelyes")).Checked.ToString();
        odsValaszok.Insert();
        gvValaszok.DataBind();
    } else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Nincs a kérdés kiválasztva!');", true);
    }
}

protected void ddlTreningek_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    odsKerdesek.SelectParameters["TrenId"].DefaultValue = ddlTreningek.SelectedValue;
    odsKerdesek.Select();
}

protected void ddlTreningek_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    odsKerdesek.SelectParameters["TrenId"].DefaultValue = ddlTreningek.SelectedValue;
    odsKerdesek.Select();
    gvKerdesek.SelectRow(-1);
}

protected void gvKerdesek_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "SelectKerdes")
    {
        string tmp = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        int selind = ((GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        odsValaszok.SelectParameters["KerdId"].DefaultValue = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        odsValaszok.Select();
        gvKerdesek.SelectedIndex = selind;
        gvKerdesek.DataBind();
    } else if (e.CommandName == "DeleteKerdes")
    {
        KerdesekDataAccessLayer.DeleteKerdes(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
        gvKerdesek.DataBind();
    } else if (e.CommandName == "EditKerdes")
    {
        int rowindex = ((GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        gvKerdesek.EditIndex = rowindex;
        gvKerdesek.DataBind();
    } else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateKerdes")
    {
        int rowindex = ((GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        int kerd_id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        odsKerdesek.UpdateParameters["KerdId"].DefaultValue = ((Label)gvKerdesek.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("Label1")).Text;
        odsKerdesek.UpdateParameters["KerdKerdes"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvKerdesek.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
        odsKerdesek.Update();
        gvKerdesek.EditIndex = -1;
        gvKerdesek.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvValaszok_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DeleteValasz")
    {
        ValaszokDataAccessLayer.DeleteValasz(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
        gvValaszok.DataBind();
    } else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateValasz")
    {
        int rowindex = ((GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        int vala_id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        odsValaszok.UpdateParameters["ValaId"].DefaultValue = ((Label)gvValaszok.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("Label1")).Text;
        odsValaszok.UpdateParameters["ValaValasz"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvValaszok.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
        odsValaszok.UpdateParameters["ValaHelyes"].DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)gvValaszok.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked.ToString();
        odsValaszok.Update();
        gvValaszok.EditIndex = -1;
        gvValaszok.DataBind();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hello ! Welcome to StackOverflow. What you've tried and what you're trying to achieve is not really clear, could you provide a more specific example?

Comment: An example for my problem: 
I want to add a new question. I write it to the textbox, then press the Insert button, and then it put my question in the sql database.

Then i want to add images as questions. I already uploaded the images before, and they are in the path, what i  write down upper.
When i want to add it, there is a dropdown list, which may contains the images name (e.g.: image1.jpg). After i choose one from the list, then the textbox automatically get filled with the path of the image. Then it works as well the normal question.

Comment: And the dropdown list must be at the footer template, because the insert function is there too.

Answer (score 0):

As i told before, the problem is the following. Here is an image for the look and for the asp code. I made an alternative solution, but i really want this too. 

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OxTP.png)

I need a code for this:
The dropdown list must contain a folder file names, and after i choose one of them, the text box on the left get filled with the path for the file like this:

~/Dokuments/10001/Teszt/Slide01.JPG 
The 10001 can be changed by the top dropdown list, which contains the different test names. If you select a test, then the path changes automatically, so it is not a problem. 

And then you can't change the textbox's content only one way, when you choose the default element from the dropdown list.